# Javascript for-loop to control button click states

Tags: javascript, navigation, click, state

I'm new to JavaScript but moving over from ActionScript, so I'm using a lot of AS3 logic and not sure what's possible and not.

I have a series of 5 dots for an image slider nav. The dots are just CSS styled dots, so I'm trying to make it so I can control the colors using element.style.backgroundColor.

Here's my script:

```
function btnFeatured(thisBtn) {
    btnFeatured_reset();
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (thisBtn === document.getElementById("dotFeat" + i)) {
            document.getElementById("dotFeat" + i).style.backgroundColor = "#ffae00";
        }
    }
}

function btnFeatured_reset() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        document.getElementById("dotFeat" + i).style.backgroundColor = "#969696";
    }
}
```

Seems to work just fine, but when I click the dot, it turns orange (ffae00) and then immediately turns back to gray (969696).

And just in case, here's the style I'm using for the dots:

```
#featured-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #969696;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: 0 14px;
}
#featured-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ffae00;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

And my html:

```
<a href='' onClick="btnFeatured(dotFeat1);" id="dotFeat1"></a>
<a href='' onClick="btnFeatured(dotFeat2);" id="dotFeat2"></a>
<a href='' onClick="btnFeatured(dotFeat3);" id="dotFeat3"></a>
<a href='' onClick="btnFeatured(dotFeat4);" id="dotFeat4"></a>
<a href='' onClick="btnFeatured(dotFeat5);" id="dotFeat5"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the HTML to

```
<a href='#' onClick="btnFeatured(this);" id="dotFeat1">test</a>
<a href='#' onClick="btnFeatured(this);" id="dotFeat2">test</a>
<a href='#' onClick="btnFeatured(this);" id="dotFeat3">test</a>
<a href='#' onClick="btnFeatured(this);" id="dotFeat4">test</a>
<a href='#' onClick="btnFeatured(this);" id="dotFeat5">test</a>
```

and the JS:

```
function btnFeatured(thisBtn) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       var state = parseInt(thisBtn.id.slice(-1),10) == i,
           elem  = document.getElementById("dotFeat" + i);

       elem.style.backgroundColor = (state ? "#ffae00" : "#969696");
    }
    return false;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DZNT5/)

Even better would be to not use inline JS, but proper event handlers.

Comment: Thank you kindly, that did the trick. =)

Yeah, I have to learn best practices, just getting my feet wet at this point.